# LDAP group with users from other directory

Tags: active-directory, openldap

In our company, we have several Active Directory servers. We have already set up an OpenLDAP server with meta backend to retrieve users from these different directories.

I would like to know if it's possible to create groups in the OpenLDAP server with users from these AD servers ?

Comment: I can't say about open Ldap, but two instances of active directory does support this, depending on the group type

Comment: Yes, but I think we have to establish a trust relationship between the two active directory ?